# Why I cannot make GPUvariable ? (Unable to allocate memory using cudaMalloc)

Tags: matlab, memory-management, cuda, gpu

I am trying to use GPUmat(MATLAB) under ubuntu.

For my system, GPUstart works well without any error message like follows :

```
Starting GPU
- GPUmat version: 0.280
- Required CUDA version: 4.2
There is 1 device supporting CUDA
CUDA Driver Version:                           4.20
CUDA Runtime Version:                          3.0

Device 0: "GeForce GT 520"
  CUDA Capability Major revision number:         2
  CUDA Capability Minor revision number:         1
  Total amount of global memory:                 1073283072 bytes
  - CUDA compute capability 2.1
...done
- Loading module EXAMPLES_CODEOPT
- Loading module EXAMPLES_NUMERICS
  -> numerics21.cubin
- Loading module NUMERICS
  -> numerics21.cubin
- Loading module RAND
```

But when I try to create variable like ' a = GPUdouble(rand(2)); '
the following error message appears

```
Error using mxNumericArrayToGPUtypePtr
Unable to allocate memory using cudaMalloc

Error in GPUdouble (line 52)
            p.slot = mxNumericArrayToGPUtypePtr(p,
            double(A));
```

I can't guess any of reason why this is hapenning. Can you give me some advice to solve this? I really appreciate for your help.

p.s) At the first time, GPUstart does not work due to the library problems. So I moved all the libraries of CUDA 4.2 to matlab library folders according to GPUmat developer's advice.

Thank you !

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you remove the `rand`? For instance, `a = GPUdouble(2)`.

Comment: You have an incompatible version of the CUDA runtime installed. GPUStart tells you "Required CUDA version: 4.2" but you have the CUDA 3.0 toolkit installed.

Comment: @talonmies please post as an answer.

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved, but make sure to include that the problem arose because matlab ships its own copy of the cuda toolkit and replaces the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to give its libraries precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incompatible version of the CUDA runtime installed. GPUStart tells you "Required CUDA version: 4.2" but you have the CUDA 3.0 toolkit installed.

You will need to update your CUDA toolkit to a supported version.